# How to remove hash from angular url using htaccess

Tags: php, angularjs

I use AngularJs with php but I don't know how to remove hash symbol using htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

That's works for me!

in the project folder create .htaccess file an then write

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```